# Reflection: Get/Set Value of Property's PropertyType's Property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

So I'm still automating my reading data into UI (working with Unity), and the situation is as such: On GameObject I have a script, in which I store variables/properties with their neat sorted attributes. I read them via reflection, for example:

```
public void insertAllFromGameObject(GameObject target, List<Type> types)
{
    var components  = target.GetComponents<Component>();
    foreach (var component in components)
    {
        if(types.Contains(component.GetType()))
        {
            var properties = component.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<ListableAttribute>().Count() > 0);
            foreach(var p in properties)
            {
                Debug.Log("VALUE: "+p.GetValue(component, null));
```

This works. Now, let's say I have a property where I want to peak in it's class, list it's properties instead with values as set in this specific property, and potentially modify them one by one for this property.

I got as far as listing, but can't figure out what to pass as argument into GetValue. Example:

```
public void insertAllFromVariable(GameObject target, List<Type> types, string propertyName)
{
    var components  = target.GetComponents<Component>();
    foreach (var component in components)
    {
        if(types.Contains(component.GetType()))
        {
            var property = component.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

            var propertysProperties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<ListableAttribute>().Count() > 0);
            foreach(var p in propertysProperties)
            {
                Debug.Log("VALUE: "+p.GetValue(component, null));
```

This last line is a problem because of course I'm not looking for it in a "component" (but rather within a property inside a component) - but what should I pass in it so that it reflects my variable's values?

Comment: You want to query the values of properties of the object that is in the _component_ property named `propertyName`. So you need to get the value object of the property `propertyName` from the `component`, and use this in your Debug.Log call. (`propertysProperties` are properties of the object stored in `component.PropertyName` - with "PropertyName" here being the concrete name of the component property you pass in the _propertyName_ string. They are not properties of _component_, hence why your second code example does not produce proper results...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified your code, sure I have no running code but concept should be clear to you:

```
public void insertAllFromVariable(GameObject target, List<Type> types, string propertyName)
        {
            var components = target.GetComponents<Component>();
            foreach (var component in components)
            {
                if (types.Contains(component.GetType()))
                {
                    PropertyInfo property = component.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                    object theRealObject = property.GetValue(component);

                    PropertyInfo[] propertysProperties = theRealObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<ListableAttribute>().Count() > 0);
                    foreach (PropertyInfo p in propertysProperties)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("VALUE: " + p.GetValue(theRealObject));
```